# Много неиспользуемых ресурсных файлов

Tags: android, android-studio

Почему при создании в Android Studio `.apk`-файла, в ресурсы добавляется очень много (десятки) неиспользуемых в приложении ресурсных фалов `.png` `.xml`?

например:
в папке `\res\drawable`

> abc_btn_borderless_material.xml
>   abc_cab_background_internal_bg.xml
>   common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark.xml
>   common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_focused.xml
>   ..................................................

в папке `\res\layout`

> abc_activity_chooser_view.xml
>   abc_action_menu_layout.xml
>   abc_search_view.xml
>   ...................

Догадываюсь, что это связано с используемой темой (я использую `Theme.AppCompat.Light`) и библиотеками, которые я использую:

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
}
```

Это приводит к увеличению размера `apk` файла и, наверное, замедляет загрузку приложения.

Можно ли удалить эти файлы из проекта?

Answer (score 2):

Включите удаление неиспользуемых ресурсов.

```
android { 
    ... 
    buildTypes { 
        release { 
            shrinkResources true 
            minifyEnabled true 
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro' 
        } 
    } 
}
```

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#shrink-resources

Есть статья про настройку ProGuard: http://jollydroid.ru/notebook/2016-12-29-ProGuard-1

Comment: Спасибо @tse.Использование Proguard (shrink + optimize) сократило размер apk c 2.5Mb до 2.0MB в основном за счет classes.dex. Но "лишние" ресурсные файлы все равно присутствуют в apk файле. И еще куда-то пропали папки values из папки res. Сгенерированный apk устанавливается и работает  нормально

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение к исключению неиспользуемых ресурсов через параметр `shrinkResources true` в конфиге gradle вы можете указать список [требуемых вам локализаций](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#unused-alt-resources), а так же других альтернативных ресурсов, что поможет существенно сократить размер итогового файла:

```
android { 

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        //для версий gradle <= 2.10
        resConfigs "en", "fr", "ru"
        resConfigs "nodpi", "xhdpi", "xxhdpi", "xxxhdpi"

        // для версий gradle > 2.10
        resConfigs = ["en", "fr", "ru"] 
        resConfigs  = ["nodpi", "xhdpi", "xxhdpi", "xxxhdpi"]
    }
    ... 
    buildTypes { 
        release { 
            shrinkResources true 
            minifyEnabled true 
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro' 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Здесь - оставить только английскую, французскую и русскую локаль и поддержку экранов с XHDPI до XXXHDPI (в новых версиях gradle изменился формат строки, в конфиге указаны оба формата, но выбрать нужно только один в зависимости от использованной в проекте версии gradle).

не секрет, что по умолчанию Android-приложение содержит локализации на более сотню языков и альтернативные ресурсы на все возможные устройства, включая телевизоры. Если свои ресурсы вы можете контролировать, то используемые в проекте библиотеки тащат с собой все возможные локализации и размеры, это поможет избавиться от них. Аналогичным образом можно исключить и другие альтернативные ресурсы, например, поддержку планшетов, если ваше приложение их не поддерживает.
Для исключенных ресурсов при запуске вашего приложения будут использоваться ресурсы по умолчанию, но вы можете вообще исключить их, указав в манифесте необходимые ограничения.

Так же сейчас появился инструмент в gradle - [Multiply APK](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html) и очень мощное средство конфигурации содержимого проекта - [раздел splits](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.Splits.html), который позволяет манипулировать не только ресурсами, локалями, но и поддерживаемыми архитектурами. Сам я им не пользовался, поэтому оставлю только ссылку на офф.док и краткий пример:

```
android {

  defaultConfig {
    ...

  }
  ...
  splits {

    density {

      // Кофигурация разрешений экрана

      enable true

      // Будут исключены из сборки
      exclude "ldpi", "xxhdpi", "xxxhdpi"

      // Оставить поддержку только следующих экранов

      compatibleScreens 'small', 'normal', 'large', 'xlarge'
    }

    language {

    enable true

    // включены в сборку языки 

    include ""en", "fr", "ru"

    }


    // Конфигурация архитектур

    abi {

      enable true

      reset()

      // Включенные в сборку архитектуры

      include "x86", "armeabi-v7a", "mips"

      // не делать универсальную сборку

      universalApk false
    }
  }
}
```

Есть команды, указывающие, какие ресурсы будут включены в проект (include), какие исключены (exclude) и тд. много разных возможностей, которые стоит изучить.